# eliminate cache in iframes

Tags: caching, iframe

I have a financial system where I create pdf forms for tax forms, receipts and etc
I have a printing page where I open the document for the client in an iframe
which suits dynamically the src to the client's pdf -

```
curUser = usrSrv.getUserFromCookie(cookie);
string formSrc = "UserForms/" + curUser.Id + ".pdf";
ifPdf.Attributes.Add("src", formSrc);
```

iI my code behind I've inserted the clear cache properties as such:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

but still - in several cases (when the user goes back from the print page for ex') - the pdf file is being saved in the cache and the system is losing its purpose.

I've figured out there might be a way with - `server.Mappath()` - but when I use it - the location seems fine and the file exists but the browser never finds the actual file or simply don't show it.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a querystring parameter to the end of the frame's URL you will get the result you need, as long as the parameter is generated fresh and unique every time. A common way of doing that is to add something like a timestamp:

```
url += "?ts=" + DateTime.Ticks;
```

or:

```
url += "?ts=" + Date.getTime();
```

Comment: i was actually realy sorpriesd cause i never figuerd out i can add this stamps on files ( i was allways sure it changes the file mark ) any how - works like a charm tnks!